# Deploying metadata to Group Edition

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, group-edition

I'm attempting to deploy a page-layout with the [ant-migration tool](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf) to a *Group Edition* org, however, when I do so using the `<sf:deploy>` call, the system attempts to run the unit-tests, and throws some strange errors about DML exceptions in my tests from inside of a package I have installed.

I created the package, and am deploying clean page-layouts so it can be uninstalled. The test-methods all pass in the packaging org (as I was able to create the beta-package).

- The same thing happens with the migration tool, as it does when I attempt to save the page-layout via the IDE, all unit-tests in the package throw an exception on DML:

`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [] stack (RTG)`

Is there anything special about deploying unpackaged code to *group edition*???

Per the documentation:

```
runAllTests
Optional. Defaults to false. If set to true, all tests are run after deploy. For deployment
to a production organization, all tests, except for those that originate from installed
runAllTests managed packages, are automatically run regardless of this argument. If any of these tests
fail when the rollbackOnError parameter is set to true, the deployment is rolled back and no changes will be made to your organization.
```

When I run with `runAllTests=false`, the operation completes successfully:

```
deployUnpackaged:
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request Id for the current deploy task: 04sR0000002jhUDIAY
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Completed
[sf:deploy] Finished request 04sR0000002jhUDIAY successfully.
```

*But*... the page-layouts have not changed to what they are in the configuration file!? The elements in the page-layout from the managed package that I'm removing are **not removed**

**Even stranger:** When I attempt to deploy the page layouts with the page-layouts from the managed package (The installed / configured state) - it reports the components with the namespace (that I downloaded from the same metadata API) don't exist in the org!! Even though the package is installed:

```
deployUnpackaged:
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request Id for the current deploy task: 04sR0000002jhUqIAI
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Completed
BUILD FAILED
/Users/jordanbaucke/Documents/forceide-workspace/jordan.baucke@gmail.com.brand/src/build/configuration/build.xml:46: FAILURES:
Error: layouts/Contact-Contact Layout.layout(174,19):In field: relatedList - no CustomField named RTG__ReadyTalkMeetingMember__c.RTG__Contact__c found
Error: layouts/Lead-Lead Layout.layout(154,19):In field: relatedList - no CustomField named RTG__ReadyTalkMeetingMember__c.RTG__Lead__c found
```

Comment: Does setting runAllTests = false help ?

Comment: I'm gonna try that right now, just updated the post with the documentation stating that it defaulted that to `false` but maybe I need to be explicit about it!

Comment: Eh it completes the deploy operation, see update

Comment: It effectively defaults to true for production. If set to false, unit tests from other installed packages don't run. It would seem the error was owing to a test from an installed package.

Comment: ah so that's related to going into a _production_ versus a _sandbox_...still doesn't explain why it succeeds but the `page-layouts` aren't changed - or that it can't find them when the package is installed ):